# How to add custom traces for firebase performance monitor inside library module?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-performance

Currently fire-base performance monitor dependency added to my app level module and works fine. Now I want to add custom traces for the application. My app module depends on other library modules. I cant able to add custom traces inside the library modules. Even I tried to add dependency to library modules also. but I got some error like library module will not support. How can I achieve to add the custom traces that are depend on library module also

Answer (score 2):

Firebase Performance Monitoring currently does not support usage in library projects that are expected to be used in any app.  It can only be used for individual apps that have Firebase fully integrated.  This is why the [instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/get-started-android) tell you to integrate into your app's top-level build.gradle.

You can [file a feature request](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) to ask for library support, but I suspect this would not happen any time soon, as it would require massive changes to the product.